# Bash script "concatenate" multi-lined variables

Tags: bash, shell, awk, echo

In a bash script I have three variables that contain multiple lines of equal length.

For example:

```
$a 
one
two
three

$b
dog
cow
fish

$c
blue
red
green
```

In what way could I echo the output to a similar format:

```
onedogblue
twocowred
threefishgreen
```

I tried a for loop of looping through each variable and echoing each line, but was not getting the desired result. Any advice?

*EDITING FOR MORE ACCURACY*
So my script will be run with a text file as an argument (./script.sh textfile) I have three variables with similar content to this variable:

```
#!/bin/sh
x=`awk 'NR>1{print $1}' $1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
```

I am manipulating the same text file from the command argument to get different parts of the file. Ultimately want to "paste" them together in this format "$x" : "$y""$z. I know there are probably more sensible ways to process the text file into the format desired, but I would like to find if there is such a way to format it in the way listed above.

Comment: If you do `cat $a`, then `$a` is a variable that expands (unsafely) to the name of a file which is printed to standard out. That's not the same as the contents of a variable.

Comment: @JoseMartinez with quotes please: `echo "$a"`.

Comment: @TomFenech I was just showing what was contained in each variable. The goal is to read through each line of each variable and print the first line of each variable on the same line, second line of each variable on the second line and so on.

Comment: Cat works on files, not variables.  So what you are catting is a file whose name is the value of $a.

Comment: The real question is: why on earth do your variables contain such newlines? please consider using an array! if these come from a file, use `mapfile -t a < file_a; mapfile -t b < file_b; mapfile -t c < file_c`. If you're hard-coding them in your script, use: `a=( one two three ) b=( dog cow red ) c=( blue red green )`. It's then rather easy to loop through all three arrays simultaneously. And your code will be much cleaner.

Comment: @JoseMartinez I was just showing what was in each variable. The cat command is not actually in my script.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I am looking into experimenting with arrays. The variables content are the result of a long list of text manipulating commands, of a text file.

Comment: You should really change your design so that you eventually end up with an array as I showed you—or maybe it'll be possible to use another tool like `awk` in a simple way. If it's concise enough, consider editing the question to include (a representative part of) your original text, what you want to achieve and the wanted result. If we get the big picture we might give you a much better solution than you already have! this will ensure you're not having an [XYproblem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I've added somewhat more of what is in the variables and a little more on the desired result. Hope this clears somethings up?

Comment: Also include the `awk` lines you're using to populate the variables `y` and `z`. I'm sure some `awk` guru will give you a wonderful one-liner (without using `tr`) that will read all three files at once and output exactly what you need. Finally I can safely assert that we really had an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Given you say you have `a long list of text manipulating commands` you are going about this completely wrong and would be much better off starting over and asking us for help with your initial input file and final desired output.

Answer (score 8):

`paste` is your friend:

```
$ paste -d' ' <(echo "$a") <(echo "$b") <(echo "$c")
one dog blue
two cow red
three fish green
```

Noting that `$a` is got through `a=$(cat a)`, with the file `a` containing the lines your provided. The same applies to `$b` and `$c`. Also, it is important to see that I am doing `echo "$a"`, with quotes around the variable, so that the format is kept. Otherwise, the new lines wouldn't appear.

`paste` does not allow `-d''` (that is, empty delimiter), so if you want to remove the spaces you can pipe to for example `tr`:

```
$ paste -d' ' <(echo "$a") <(echo "$b") <(echo "$c") | tr -d ' '
onedogblue
twocowred
threefishgreen
```

Comment: @swam what do you mean?

Comment: The paste command seems to fail when I use it in a .sh script

Comment: @swam I cannot see what you see in your screen, so if you want to get help try to give a more descriptive analysis of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about not having the quotes in the echo so that the newlines are removed then use sed to remove the white spaces.

```
$a="one
> two
> three"
$
$echo "$a"
one
two
three
$
$echo $a
one two three
$
$echo $a | sed 's/ //g'
onetwothree
$
```

Comment: Because without the quotes, your expansion is subject to pathname expansion. By the way, if you only wanted this, you would do: `echo "${a//[[:space:]]}"`. But OP's problem is different: OP wants to “shuffle” the three variables.